# Parsed HTML e-mail section wont display in browser

Tags: php, parsing, echo

When a client receives a review on the web from a specific service, that service sends and e-mail that notifies of the new review. The content of the e-mail includes the review itself, and source information, the content comes as (e-mail header, e-mail body PART 1(plain text) and e-mail body PART 2 (HTML). I need to parse the HTML section of those e-mails and push them out to a new flatfile for PHP include on the clients testimonials page.

I am successfully able to connect to my mail service, and parse section 2 of the test e-mail i am using to test with. the problem is that when the output is viewed in the browser it's simply blank. But when I view source - all of the content inclusive of HTML code/structure/css  is there. I'm at a loss as to why I see nothing (plaint text or HTML) on the front end of the browser but see everything in source view.

**Here is my code:**

```
$login="*email user name*";
$password="*email password*";

$connection = imap_open('{pop.secureserver.net:995/novalidate-cert/pop3/ssl}', $login, $password);
$count = imap_num_msg($connection); /* get number of messages on server */
$i = 46; /* message 46 is the message being used to test this */


$header = imap_header($connection, $i);
$body = imap_fetchbody($connection,$i,"2"); /* grab section 2 of e-mail (HTML) */
$prettydate = date("F jS Y", $header->udate); /* not necessary just part of testing response */

        if (isset($header->from[0]->personal)) {
            $personal = $header->from[0]->personal;
        } else {
            $personal = $header->from[0]->mailbox;
        }

        $email = "$personal <{$header->from[0]->mailbox}@{$header->from[0]->host}>";
        echo "On $prettydate, $email said <hr>";
        echo $body;
        echo "<hr>";

imap_close($connection);
```

**First 15 lines of "view source" after PHP response from within chrome.**

```
On August 3rd 2014, New Review Notifications <pl-no-reply@reviews.com> said <hr><!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.=
w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"> <html xmlns=3D"http://www.w3=
.org/1999/xhtml"> <head> <meta http-equiv=3D"Content-Type" content=3D"text/=
html; charset=3Dutf-8" /> <title></title> <style type=3D"text/css"> .Extern=
alClass{display:block !important;} .yshortcuts, .yshortcuts a, .yshortcuts =
a:link, .yshortcuts a:visited, .yshortcuts a:hover, .yshortcuts a span{ col=
or:#008ec5; text-decoration:none !important; border-bottom:none !important;=
 background:none !important; } body{margin:0;} p{margin:0 !important;} </st=
yle> </head> <body marginheight=3D"0" marginwidth=3D"0" leftmargin=3D"0" to=
pmargin=3D"0" bgcolor=3D"#ffffff"> <table width=3D"100%" cellpadding=3D"0" =
cellspacing=3D"0" bgcolor=3D"#ffffff"> <tr> <td height=3D"25" style=3D"back=
ground-color: #88939B" colspan=3D"3"></td> </tr> <tr> <td width=3D"50%" val=
ign=3D"top"> <table width=3D"100%" cellpadding=3D"0" cellspacing=3D"0" styl=
e=3D"height: 232px;"> <tr> <td style=3D"background-color: #88939B; height: =
232px; display: block">&nbsp;</td> </tr> </table> </td> <td width=3D"632"> =
```

PS - can someone with higher rep add imap-fetchbody to tag list if applicable, it wont let me.

Comment: that's a complete html document, including `<html>` and `<body>` tags. you can't embed html-in-html like that. you'd need to use an iframe to make a completely separate document area, or extract the email/'s `<body>` content and stuff only that into your page. Plus, if that `=` line-end stuff is literally in there too, then it's a CORRUPTED html document. `span {col=or:#008ec5}` is not valid CSS, `to=pmargin=3d"0"` etc.. is not a valid tag attribute, blah blah blah.

Comment: @MarcB   Yeah, I can see that as the potential problem, is there any existing php built in functions that are meant to clean up the encoding that the e-mail server is adding? i'd like to be left with just the valid HTML structured data? (ie - stripping out the = sign and or any other misc. entities the mail server is encoding in there?)

Comment: @MarcB Thank you, your comment was part of the finding both problem & solution so best I can do is say thanks and +1 the comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two problems here: a. encoding, b. content display.

**Encoding**

Somewhere in header (or body) is a property `encoding`.
This tell's you how your mail content is encoded.
You can then use these pieces of information to revert the encoding.
It might be `$body->encoding`, instead of `$header->encoding`.

```
$body = imap_fetchbody($connection,$i,"2");

if ($header->encoding == 4) {
        $body = quoted_printable_decode($body);
}

if ($header->encoding == 3) {
        $body = base64_decode($body);
}

echo $body; // now body should have the correct encoding
```

Give this a try, too:

```
$body = imap_fetchbody($connection,$i, 1.2); <-- instead of 2
```

**Content Display**

As Marc B already pointed out, it's not possible to render a complete HTML page inside a HTML page, without an iframe. An iframe is the easiest way to display this.

But you have several options here, from tag-removal over body-extraction.
If you remove the "important" tags, you get the content.
preg_matching for `<body>.*</body>` should work, too.

```
$body = str_replace('<html>', '', $body);
$body = str_replace('<head>', '', $body);
$body = str_replace('<title>', '', $body);
$body = str_replace('<body>', '', $body);
$body = str_replace('</body>', '', $body);
$body = str_replace('</html>', '', $body);
```

Comment: Thank You!, I had seen the encoding reference in the PHP docs earlier but wasn't understanding how to apply it or if it was needed in this case. I did get it to work through your example though. Thanks!

Comment: glad you figured it out :)